# mysql_result returns filed name as result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm kinda new at webprograming. I've only studied it for a year or so.

My problem is the following. For some reason when I use this query(in phpadmin wampserver), the last 4 field results are the field names.

```
SELECT  `latin_name` ,  
    `group` ,  
    `name` ,  
    `continent` , 
    `country` ,  
    `position` ,  
    `hight_min` ,  
    `hight_max` ,  
    `light_min` ,  
    `light_max` ,  
    `temp_min` ,  
    `temp_max` ,  
    `nk_min` ,  
    `nk_max` ,  
    `gh_min` ,  
    `gh_max` ,  
    `ph_min` ,  
    `ph_max` ,  
    `growth_rate` ,  
    'growth_min',  
    'growth_max', 
    'gfactor',  
    'period' 
FROM  `plants` 
WHERE continent LIKE  'As' 
    AND growth_rate LIKE  'slow' 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: And the data in your database for those fields is good data?

Comment: The type of quotes used for the last four field names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a mixture of quote types. The first few fields use `` ` ``, but the last 4 use `'`, which turn them into string literals.

Try:

```
SELECT  `latin_name` ,  
`group` ,  
`name` ,  
`continent` , 
`country` ,  
`position` ,  
`hight_min` ,  
`hight_max` ,  
`light_min` ,  
`light_max` ,  
`temp_min` ,  
`temp_max` ,  
`nk_min` ,  
`nk_max` ,  
`gh_min` ,  
`gh_max` ,  
`ph_min` ,  
`ph_max` ,  
`growth_rate` ,  
`growth_min`,  
`growth_max`, 
`gfactor`,  
`period` 
FROM  `plants` 
WHERE continent LIKE  'As' 
AND growth_rate LIKE  'slow' 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems that was the problem.
THX a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have apostrophes (`'`) instead of backticks (`` ` ``) for these last 4 fields.